# Atributo required do input não funciona depois de utilizar jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Olá,

Ao utilizar jquery para desabilitar o botão submit após ser enviado uma vez o atríbuto required no input não funciona mais.

HTML

```
<form id="ajax" action="#teste" method="POST">
        <p class="remodal-text">Nome</p>
        <input type="text" name="nome" required>
         <p class="remodal-text">E-mail</p>
        <input type="email" name="email" required>
         <p class="remodal-text">Assunto</p>
        <input type="text" name="assunto" required>
         <p class="remodal-text" required>Mensagem</p>
        <textarea name="mensagem" name="mensagem"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn-submit" >
      <div id="enviado" style="width: 100%; height: 60px;"></div>

        </form>
```

JS

```
 $(function(){
     $(".btn-submit").click(function () {
       $(".btn-submit").attr("disabled", true);
       $('#ajax').submit();
     });
   });
```

Exemplo no CodePen: http://codepen.io/flashpremium/pen/gpZZRv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o evento `submit` no lugar do `click` para enviar o formulário, exemplo:

```
$(function(){
    $("#ajax").on('submit', function() {
        $(".btn-submit").attr("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

Ao adicionar um *listener* no evento de `submit` do seu formulário, você assegura que as validações dentro dele sejam todas disparadas, afinal, elas rodam antes deste evento. Agora quando você usa `click` no botão do formulário, seria como se você estivesse falando: *"Ei, escute apenas quando este botão for clicado, não interessando se o formulário foi enviado ou não"*. Logo, o evento dispara apenas com o botão, antes de qualquer evento do próprio formulário, o que atrapalha a validação do mesmo.

Inclusive, utilizando o `submit` para disparar seu formulário AJAX permite usar a funcionalidade padrão dos browsers de enviar um formulário pressionando a tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

<sup>Obs.: Note que eu removi a linha `$("#ajax").submit()` visto que como agora estamos tratando o próprio evento de submit, ele já será enviado de qualquer forma.</sup>

Comment: Isso resolve o problema, obrigado Kazzkiq!